# Какая максимальная длина поля с собщением об ошибке

Tags: mysql, логирование

Часть [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535316/show-warnings-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83) хочу решить здесь:
Какая максимальная длинна сообщения об ошибке (или предупреждения) после выполнения запроса?

Речь идет о третьем поле **Message**.

```
mysql> select capid from cap where (seklect bla);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bla)' at line 1

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1064 | You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bla)' at line 1 |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
mysql>
```

Экспериментальным путем выяснил что такой запрос:

```
$q = 'update usopt set usname=? set usplace=? set usadlog=? set uslife=? set showfr=? set sendpm=? where uid_usopt=?';
```

выдает такую ошибку (она НЕ обрезана! скриншот в потверждение) [image: сообщение об ошибке]
То что я так хотел провести обновление - так это у меня не в первый раз  А еще я постоянно путаю OR AND, а потом по полчаса или полдня не могу понять почему код не работает так как нужно.

Но это выдает такое функция

```
echo (mysqli_error($ddb));
```

В то же время, такой запрос выполненный в консоли:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? set usplace=? set usadlog=? set uslife=? set showfr=? set sendpm=? where uid_u' at line 1
```

А show warnings выдает такое:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1064 | You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? set usplace=? set usadlog=? set uslife=? set showfr=? set sendpm=? where uid_u' at line 1 |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Думаю, что 226 и есть максимум символов в описании ошибки.

Вопрос полностью еще не решен, но разгадка близко. Было предположение о том что есть какой-то параметр который влияет на длину сообщения, но ниже написали что это не так.

Answer (score 2):

Полный список сообщений можно найти в исходных [кодах MySQL](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/share/errmsg-utf8.txt). С учетом того, что часть полей может включать в себя SQL-фрагменты, названия таблиц и полей, можно сказать, что количество символов в этой строке между 256 (2^8) и 65536 (2^16).

Comment: вот в том то и дело, что невозможно угадать длину этого сообщения :( Это нужно примерно посчитать наиболее длинный запрос в коде и + к нему некторе количество символов.(?)

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy Запрос может со временем изменить, лучше оставлять изрядный запас.

Comment: ну так я и написал "+ некоторе количество символов". Главное найти баланс, чтобы не  обрезало ошибки.

Comment: НЕЕЕТТ. У меня возникли смутные сомненья. Я так думаю что в php имеется некий параметр, который ограничивает эту длину. Почему так думаю я ДОписал в вопросе.

Comment: нет такого параметра, mysql-парсер вот так выдает ошибки. просто запуская из консоли или из скрипта вы получаете разные ошибки, а выдает он их так потому, что оптимизатор переделал запрос

Comment: возможно, вы сможете получить более читаемое сообщение об ошибке отключив все опции оптимизатора - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html

Comment: Если такого параметра нет значит максимальная длинна 226 символов.? НО АЖ никак не 65000 символов(?).

Comment: есть еще у php  в настройках log_errors_max_len, попробуйте, но все-таки я удивлюсь если оно сработает

Comment: ну да, только это относится php. Более чем уверен что это не оно. Потому что в чистой мскл консоли длина 226 символов. НО я проверю ;%))

Comment: кстати это сообщ об ошибке синтаксиса. а другие будут еше короче.(?) Завтра разберусь.